# Ruby remove `\"` from a string?

Tags: ruby

How do I remove `\"` from a string?

Example:

```
'"\"asdasd"\"'.gsub('\"', '') # => "\"asdasd\""
```

Why is `\"` not removed?

Comment: You need to make clear what you mean by `\"`. Do you mean `'\"'`, or `"\""`? The answer depends on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is removed. The `\"` in the output is not a backslash followed by a double quote, it's just a double quote character that's escaped because `inspect` prints strings in double quotes. If you try to print the string, it'll come out as:

```
"asdasd"
```

To expand on this a bit: `'"\"asdasd"\"'` (which can also be written using double quotes as `"\"\\\"asdasd\"\\\""`) is a string that contains a double quote, followed by a backslash, followed by a double quote, followed by asdasd, followed by a double quote, followed by a backslash, followed by a double quote.

Your call to `gsub` removes the two occurrences of backslashes followed by double quotes. The result is `"\"asdasd\""`, which could also be written as `'"asdasd"'` and is a string containing a double quote, followed by asdasd, followed by a double quote. So the backslash-double quotes were removed, but the simple double quotes weren't. I assume that's the intended behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In ruby special symbol is preceding by backslash when convert into string.
i.e `"\"` to the `\"\\\"`

Check this you will understand

```
'"\"asdasd"\"'                               # => "\"\\\"asdasd\"\\\""
'"\"asdasd"\"'.gsub("\\", '')                # => "\"\"asdasd\"\""
'"\"asdasd"\"'.gsub("\\", '').gsub("\"", '') # => "asdasd"
```

Answer (score 0):

How is this ?

```
str = '"\"asdasd"\"'
p str[/\w+/] # => "asdasd"
```

Answer (score 0):

It did remove them.  Here's what the string looks like when `inspect`ed before the change:

```
'"\"asdasd"\"'               # => "\"\\\"asdasd\"\\\""
```

And here's after:

```
'"\"asdasd"\"'.gsub('\"','') # => "\"asdasd\""
```

So it previously had some backslash-quotation mark sequences in it.  Now it just has quotation marks.